# MyBB attachment not showing up

Tags: php, .htaccess, forum, mybb

I am experiencing a quite weird issue on my client's MyBB instance. Attachments upload works, but I can't see them when readin the thread after saving the modifications.

At first I thought it was a permission issue (chmod or htaccess), but the upload works. I can see uploaded attachments in the "/uploads/201503/" folder. I see one thumbnail file and another one with the ".attach" file extension, which is in fact my jpg image when renaming the ".attach" extension to ".jpg". So upload works.

Now looking at the database "attachments" table, I can see the uploaded attachment row. The "attachname" field shows "201503/post_2_1425271978_8162c40a2a603edc2b441bd78460f9a7.attach", which is exactly the my uploaded attachment. So, persistence to database works.

I tried removing all my htaccess files and putting chmod to 777... negative. It's not going anywhere.

Does anybody here already faced that issue?

I have searched the forum before posting.. some very old threads have showed up, but unfortunately the op did not post the solution.

I got no error/warning message whatsoever.

Many thanks for help.

Charles

Comment: To the attention of the downvoter, would you mind sharing with us actually WHY you did downvote my question?

Answer (score 1):

Check that attachments size in db and real size are the same. If they are not, `Content-length` will be wrong and some browsers just fail.

Answer (score 1):

Also, simply check that the permissions are such that guests can't view the attached image.